# Which package now support facebook ads in react-native?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

After Facebook ads publish new version audience-network-sdk, my project use package expo-ads-facebook have audience-network-sdk is 5.1.1 is no longer support for android. Please help me, Tks

Comment: Hey @Tuấn Did you reach out to a solution ?

Comment: I am also working hard to configure facebook audience network within my react-native app but without expo, as i am using react-native cli

Answer (score 0):

try `'react-native-fbads'`

npm link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbads

github link:https://github.com/callstack/react-native-fbads